# How to Display selected values from a dictionary to a listbox

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm busy making a program with a search function where a person will enter for example subject "Information Systems" in a GUI Tk entry, and i want it to display on those records which has Information systems. Here is some code:

```
StudentList[[Tom,Information systems],[John,Computers]]
```

So basically if I type Information systems, it must show in my listbox:
"Tom, Information Systems"

How do i make this search function work?
This is what i have tried

```
for i in students:
    if viewcode == True:
        lb1.insert(END,str(i))
```

Comment: So... What have you tried? Please see: [MCVE]

Comment: i have  put it in the question

Comment: What is `viewcode`? Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does roughly what you are looking for. Enter your search term in the Entry box and press Return. It will then populate the Listbox with any matching entries from the student list.

```
from tkinter import *

student_list = [['Tom','Information Systems'],['John','Computers']]


class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,**kw):
        Frame.__init__(self,master=parent,**kw)
        self.searchValue = StringVar()

        self.searchBox = Entry(self,textvariable=self.searchValue)
        self.searchBox.pack()
        self.resultList = Listbox(self)
        self.resultList.pack()

        self.searchBox.bind('<Return>',self.update)

    def update(self,e):
        print("*")
        self.resultList.delete(0,END)
        searchkey = self.searchValue.get()
        for student in student_list:
            if searchkey == student[0]:
                self.resultList.insert(END,str(student))
            elif searchkey == student[1]:
                self.resultList.insert(END,str(student))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```